# Algebraically closed field and polynomials

Tags: field-theory

There is the problem:

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $0$ with the condition: If $f(x) \in F[x]$ has no roots in $F$, then the degree of $f(x)$ is a multiple of $21$. Prove that $F$ is algebraically closed.

Actually I don't have any idea about it, any hint is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The key fact is that 21 is not prime.  You will want to prove that if $f(x)$ whose degree is a multiple of 21 has no roots in $F$, then in fact there is a polynomial of degree 3 or 7 which has no roots in $F$.  This violates the hypothesis, so all polynomials must actually split (so $F$ is algebraically closed).

Try thinking about the Galois group of $f$ and its subgroups.  Use the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

Comment: you mean thinking to the (supposed to be a field) $F[x] / (f(x))$ ?